# Can I get a tip snapshot of a mercurial repository, without doing a complete clone?

Tags: mercurial, clone

Say I have a repository on another machine whose entire history is to big to clone locally.  If I have no intention of submitting any changes back to that repository, there's no reason that I shouldn't be able to just take a snapshot of the tip.  Is there a way to do this, or am I going to find myself working around this with an rsync hack or something similar?

If it helps, in my case, the remote repository is provided by mercurial-server through an ssh tunnel.

Comment: My final solution was to have the server keep its view of the repository up-to-date at all times by having a hook do an 'hg update'  From there, it is simple enough to do an rsync, excluding the .hg directory.  It suffers the potential hazzard that someone could check in while the rsync is running, but the particulars of my business case make this tremendously unlikely and easily detectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hg archive` to create an unversioned archive for any revision. It does not work with ssh URL, so you'd have to run it on the remote host then scp the archive back.

Comment: I think I'll stick a service on the server that will create an archive on demand and make it available via scp.

Answer (score 3):

The standard CGI script for Mercurial lets you download zip and tarballs for any revision. See the [`web.allow_archive` setting](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web). You can also see this with `hg serve`, which runs the same code as the CGI script underneath.